# Drawing dashed line in java

Tags: java, graphics

My problem is that I want to draw a dashed line in a panel. I'm able to do it, but it drew my border in a dashed line as well.

Can someone please explain why? I'm using paintComponent to draw and draw straight to the panel.

This is the code to draw a dashed line:

```
public void drawDashedLine(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        //float dash[] = {10.0f};
        Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(3, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{9}, 0);
        g2d.setStroke(dashed);
        g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You're modifying the `Graphics` instance passed into `paintComponent()`, which is also used to paint the borders.

Instead, make a copy of the `Graphics` instance and use that to do your drawing:

```java
public void drawDashedLine(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){

  // Create a copy of the Graphics instance
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

  // Set the stroke of the copy, not the original 
  Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(3, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL,
                                  0, new float[]{9}, 0);
  g2d.setStroke(dashed);

  // Draw to the copy
  g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

  // Get rid of the copy
  g2d.dispose();
}
```

Comment: I have a quick question: in which context I have to clone the current Graphics? Obviously cloning every graphics instance is not necessary :)

Comment: Anytime you modify the Graphics object. Settings like the color will probably get set again by the other paint methods, but settings like the stroke aren't always reset. It might even vary between different look and feels, so better safe than sorry.

Comment: Exhibit 9001 of Java Swing/AWT being a messy, inconsistent, unpredictable API :)

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility would be to store the values used in swap local variables (Ex. Color , Stroke etc...) and set them back to the on use Graphics.

something like :

```
Color original = g.getColor();
g.setColor( // your color //);

// your drawings stuff

g.setColor(original);
```

this will work for whatever change you decide to do to the Graphics.

Answer (score 2):

You modified the graphics context by setting a stroke, and subsequent methods such as `paintBorder()` use the same context and thus inherit all modifications you made.

**Solution:**
clone the context, use it for painting and dispose it afterwards.

**Code:**

```
// derive your own context  
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
// use context for painting
...
// when done: dispose your context
g2d.dispose();
```