# How to make duplicate components in AWT that can have different positions?

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

```
import java.awt.*;      
import java.awt.event.*;            
public class StackOFlow {           
    static Frame frame = new Frame();       
    static Label dot = new Label(".");      
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        new StackOFlow();   
        for (int i = 1; i < 1600; i += 30) {    
            dot.setBounds(i, 400, 80, 30);
            frame.add(dot);
        }   
    }       
    public StackOFlow() {       
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setLayout(null);  
        frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);   
    }       
}
```

I am trying to make a graphing program in Java, where, based on the desired function, dots will be created in an AWT frame to make a dotted line. I am wondering if there is a way to create a single component(the dot) many times, so that I don't need to declare lots of Labels that are just dots.

Comment: Id use a JPanel and draw some dots on it

Comment: No, a component can only be added to one container once. It always checks if it already has a parent and removes itself.

Comment: Use Swing instead of AWT

Comment: Yes, but you'd probably just end up with a customised `JLabel` or other component, which are simply added to some kind of `List`.  You might find a custom painting route or `JFreeChart` might be more suitable

Comment: *"I am wondering if there is a way to create a single component(the dot) many times, so that I don't need to declare lots of Labels that are just dots."* Loops make light work of that, but I agree with @MadProgrammer that custom painting / JFreeChart is a better way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments to your question: It might not be a good idea to do this for various reasons.

Now,how to do it if you have to:

1) If you **don't need** the dots at a later time you simple create new instanced or placement:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 1600; i += 30) {  
        Label tempDot = new Label(".");  
        tempDot .setBounds(i, 400, 80, 30);
        frame.add(tempDot );
    }
```

2) If you **need** the references of all the single dots or later, you might want to put them in a List:

```
 List<Label> dots = new ArrayList<Label>();
 [...]

    for (int i = 1; i < 1600; i += 30) {  
        Label tempDot = new Label(".");  
        tempDot .setBounds(i, 400, 80, 30);
        frame.add(tempDot );
        dots.add(tempDot);
    }
```

3) If the `Label`s are only means to an end (dotted line) check here for example: [Drawing dashed line in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989082/drawing-dashed-line-in-java)