# Add a JComponent via Child to Parent

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent

[image]

I want to accomplish something very similar to the image a Rectangle whit a Selector Line.

Basically, I have a Rectangle and I want to have a selector line all around it.
For that, I wanted to create an additional JComponent.

At the moment I can only draw the Rectangle. How could I get the parentPanel JPanel inside the Rectangle class, so that I could add the selector?

```
public class TestPanel extends JFrame {

    public class Rectangle extends JComponent {

        public Rectangle(){
            setBounds(x1, y1, x2, y2);

            JPanel Selector = new JPanel();
            //Adds Selector to parentPanel within Rectangle
            //setBounds(x1-1, y1-1, x2+1, y2+1)
            //!Problem parent is initially null! cant even a use property
            //Life hacks?
        }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }

    public TestPanel() {
        Rectangle Rectangle = new Rectangle();
        JPanel parentFrame = new JPanel();
        parentFrame.add(Rectangle);

        setSize(200, 200);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPanel();
    }
}
```

If I try to add the selector inside the rectangle, it will get out of the drawing area. If I resize the drawing area, it won't be scalable for later development.

If possible I would avoid dual binding like:

```
public TestPanel() {
            Rectangle Rectangle = new Rectangle();
            JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel();
            parentPanel.add(Rectangle);
            Rectangle.addParent(parentPanel)
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Consider telling the details of your goal and your problem achieving your goal as well as asking a specific and answerable question. Please check out the [ask] for more on-site best practices. Also, consider telling what the current code does that you don't desire and what it doesn't do that you currently desire it to do. I cannot stress how important the details are to helping us to understand both your code and your problem.

Comment: Could you clarify more, what I'm missing?  question, explanation or code inst clear?

Comment: Perhaps it's me, but I have no idea what you're asking, what you need help with. What do you mean by "getting the parent within the rectangle"? What parent for instance? Also, what user experience are you trying to achieve, as you may be approaching this wrong, and the details will help us to understand things a lot better.

Comment: In the image I provided, there is a square. Just like in paint. What I want to accomplish is a way to make that dashed line around the square.

Comment: This seems like a purely painting issue and does not seem to involve creating a new component, but again, it's not altogether clear. Why are you creating a new component to do this? What is this "selector" supposed to be doing?

Comment: For example, you would draw a dashed line within paintComponent by changing the Stroke property of a Graphics2D object as per [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989082/drawing-dashed-line-in-java/21989406), but this would have nothing to do with using multiple Swing components.

Comment: This selector will behave very similar to the one u find in the paint(allow resize). However, for now, is just a guideline, for the user. The reason im creating another component is because if i create a component, lets call it componentA and add to it a componentB. ComponentB is only "visible" inside the componentA visible area.

Comment: I can show how the selector is currently created and what I have so far?

Answer (score 1):

Again, I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to achieve. If what you wish to create is a user-created dashed line, one that can change with mouse press/drag/release, then you don't need to create a new component but rather use a MouseAdapter as a MouseListener and MouseMotionListener, all to help you create the Rectangle, and then simply draw the Rectangle with a dashed line using an appropriate Stroke, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21989406/522444).

For example, something like would create a dashed line that is user-selectable:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SelectorPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 650;
    private static final Stroke DASHED_STROKE = new BasicStroke(2, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
            BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[] { 5 }, 0);
    private static final Color DASHED_COLOR = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    private Rectangle rectangle = null;

    public SelectorPanel() {
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        private Point p1 = null;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            p1 = e.getPoint();
            rectangle = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (p1 != null) {
                createRectangle(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (p1 != null) {
                createRectangle(e);
                p1 = null;
            }
        }

        private void createRectangle(MouseEvent e) {
            Point p2 = e.getPoint();
            int x = Math.min(p1.x, p2.x);
            int y = Math.min(p1.y, p2.y);
            int width = Math.abs(p1.x - p2.x);
            int height = Math.abs(p1.y - p2.y);
            rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            repaint();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (rectangle != null) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setColor(DASHED_COLOR);
            g2.setStroke(DASHED_STROKE);
            g2.draw(rectangle);
            g2.dispose();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SelectorPanel mainPanel = new SelectorPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SelectorPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is very good, but is not exactly what i was looking for. I used your example to try to explain better, see if is more clear?

Comment: @Joao, then you will want to adapt this code or write your own so that the mouse press method checks if a press is near an existing line